# jQuery function acts asynchronously

Tags: jquery

This outputs 456 to both the `Data` element and the console (as expected):

```js
function getData() {
  jQuery('#Data').html(456);
}

jQuery(function($) {
  getData();
  console.log($('#Data').html());  //456
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Data">123</div>
```

---

This outputs 456 to the `Data` element, but the console shows it unchanged as 123:

```js
function getData() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#Data').html(456);
  });
} //getData    

jQuery(function($) {
  getData();
  console.log($('#Data').html());  //123
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Data">123</div>
```

---

Putting `console.log()` in a timeout fixes it:

```js
function getData() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#Data').html(456);
  });
} //getData    

jQuery(function($) {
  getData();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($('#Data').html());  //456
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Data">123</div>
```

---

I can work around the issue, but it's surprising.

Is this a bug or expected functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected funtionality. When you do

```
function getData() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#Data').html(456);
  });
}
```

you are attaching a handler to an event. Namely, the document ready event.
That is because

```
jQuery(function($){
});
```

is shorthand for

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
});
```

You are doing it twice. Once generally when you do

```
jQuery(function($) {
  getData();
  console.log($('#Data').html());  //123
});
```

and within that handler, you attach another handler when you call `getData`.

So the console.log executes before the next event handler you attached within executes.

Comment: @RickHitchcock, in your example, no. This is because you attach the event handler only once when you call `getData`

Comment: In my second and third examples, I attach it twice(?)

Comment: @RickHitchcock, no. In your third example, you attach it once(again, because you are calling `getData` once which attaches it). In your first example you are not attaching it at all

Comment: @RickHitchcock, oh sorry, in your third example you are attaching it twice. Once in `getData` and generally after that function

Comment: @RickHitchcock, and in your first example you are attaching it once

Comment: Hmm, I have a proprietary dollar sign function ($), which I'm in the process of moving to jQuery.  So I use `jQuery(function($)` within certain functions to do that.  Might a better method be to simply add `var $ = jQuery;` to those functions?

Comment: @RickHitchcock, sorry, I totally misread your code. The answer is semi the same now. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Oh, man, I just realized what I was doing wrong.  I'll post my own answer, but I'm giving you the credit.

Comment: @RickHitchcock, no need. If your answer better provides a solution to the question, please feel free to accept that one

Answer (score 0):

I now realize my mistake, and thanks to @AmmarCSE for the help.

I have my own dollar sign function, and I've been doing this in some functions so that I could use jQuery's function instead:

```
jQuery(function($) {
});
```

What I *should* be doing is this:

```
(function($) {
})(jQuery);
```

Then everything works as expected:

```js
function getData() {
  (function($) {
    $('#Data').html(456);
  })(jQuery);
} //getData    

(function($) {
  getData();
  console.log($('#Data').html());  //456
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Data"></div>
```